# Getting AxiosError: Read ECONNRESET in calling API but working fine with Fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am calling NSE API but getting the following error:

```
AxiosError: read ECONNRESET
    at AxiosError.from 
... 
{
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  errno: -4077,
...
  },
  cause: Error: read ECONNRESET
      at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
    errno: -4077,
    code: 'ECONNRESET',
    syscall: 'read'
  }
}
```

But the below code is working as expected while calling JSONPlaceholder API.

```
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();

// const API_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
const API_URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/holiday-master?type=trading";

const callApi = async () => {
    try {
        console.log("HIT");
        const res = await axios.get(API_URL);
        if(res.status === 200) {
            console.log("DATA: ",res.data);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    callApi();
    res.send('Demo...');
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server runnning...");
});
```

Below is a package.json file content.

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

I also call NSE API with fetch() it works fine but when calling with axios it gives error as you saw above.

How can I resolve this error?